# Kendo UI Razor - How To Add CSS Class to Html.Kendo().AutoComplete(), Button(), MultiSelect() And Other Input Fields?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

How can you add a CSS Class, not explicit inline styling, to a Kendo MVC UI control?

No matter what we've tried we cannot add CSS Classes to Kendo UI HTML helpers.
It only adds its own "k-" class.
You can add an style attribute with explicit width and styling, 
but not a class,

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "please-dont-hard-code-widths" })
```

or

```
new HtmlAttributes(new {new { @class = "please-dont-hard-code-widths" } })
```

do nothing at all.

** Update, this issue also happens with @Html.EditorFor() when Kendo is part of the project, it won't accept classes though the documentation says it does.  We have to use explicit input types like TextBoxFor() which defeats having the class model drive the form types.

The  other regular Razor HTML Helpers do it fine, but not the Kendo ones.
It's seems impossible Telerik wouldn't support something this basic for for the display layer.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a number of their controls, like the ones mentioned above, that for some reason don't use those classes.  A lot of the controls, do however, such as the Grid.

Answer (score 1):

I too have faced this problem a few times and even went as far as creating my own helpers as well as editor templates but here are two ways I have achieved this in some controls. It does always add its own class but using the below techniques I have managed to inject my own attributes in the generated tags.

Note, I used MVC5.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "form-control" } })

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MobileNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control validateNumericInput", @aria_describedby = "mobile-addon" } })
```